# Auto run app when screen is lock

Tags: android, screen

I want to make my app auto run before screen is off (app run while screen still off), is it possible? I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
  KeyguardManager   mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager)  getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
  KeyguardLock   mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("AndroidSQLite");
  mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

In AndroidManifest i put:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to get notification before screen ON/OFF.

But below are the intent send for screen off/on:
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF